# Evaluation of conditional expressions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a recursive algorithm  that evaluates an expression of the type: `operator` `variable` and functions which returns `true/false`.

```
 [A] = [B] - [c]
 functionA(1,2) = functionB(3,4,5)
 functionA(functionC(a,b)) = functionB(3,4,5)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to start and what method to use. I can use stack or anything.
I am trying to do this in *Javascript*.

Any logic/idea is welcome.

Comment: maybe you add some (more) examples and apply some fomat...

Comment: question is absolutely unclear, hard to get it really.

Comment: I need to evaluate an expression to find whether the result is true /false.      eg.2=1+1           variables can be a function also.Function might return a value.Like here 2 can be a function say FunctionA(arg1,arg2).So FunctionA(arg1,arg2) = 1+1.Here this returns true if result of function evaluation is 2 and 1+1 result is also 2.

Comment: Hope this explains well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this, a collection of functions and a stack based iteration over the commands in a [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) style.

In the output you see the actual command and stack.

```js
var $ = {
        '===': function (b) { return function (a) { return a === b; }; },
        '+': function (b) { return function (a) { return a + b; }; },
        '-': function (b) { return function (a) { return a - b; }; },
        '1/x': function (a) { return 1 / a; },
    },
    commands = [3, 2, '+', 9, 4, '-', '==='],
    result = commands.reduce(function (stack, command) {
        var temp;
        if ($[command]) {
            temp = $[command];
            while (typeof temp === 'function') {
                temp = temp(stack.pop());
            }
            stack.push(temp);
        } else {
            stack.push(command);
        }
        document.write('<pre>' + command + ': ' + JSON.stringify(stack, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
        return stack;
    }, [])[0];

document.write(result);
```